# How to fix and test a race-condition in my Rails 4 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I had the following code in my model. Someone rightly pointed out that the `make_default!` method could cause a race condition:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  def make_default!
    State.update_all(default: false)
    update!(default: true)
  end
end
```

because if two people are updating the record at the same time, two `State` objects could end up being set to `default: true`.

I used this workaround by using ActiveRecord locks:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  def make_default!
    # Prevent race condition using database-level locks.
    State.transaction do
      State.where.not(id: id).lock(true).update_all(default: false)
      State.where(id: id).lock(true).first.update!(default: true)
    end
  end
end
```

but someone pointed out that this could cause other potential bugs.
I'm wondering what the best way to implement locks would be, as well as how I'd go about testing the model spec (using RSpec)?

Any help much appreciated :) thanks!

Comment: I _think_ just wrapping it in a transaction should actually be sufficient, no need for the locks. You could do that, and then test it by putting a big `sleep` in between the update_all and the update on one execution, and running another one without that, and seeing what happens. I think the last one should win, and there should be only default true. You could also accept there might be more than one default true, and when looking up the default always take the last one (with updated_at timestamp) -- assume default is the LAST one to have true set.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to circumvent the problem entirely would be to keep the reference of the default entry elsewhere rather than relying on boolean true/false columns.

So you can have a `default_entities` table that has a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) with State:

```
entity_id | entity_type
-----------------------
        1 |       State
```

Now updating the default value requires modifying just a single row and hence is an [atomic operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)).

It will be an atomic operation even if you use a separate key-value store but in that case you will have to handle rollback on transaction failures yourself.

Alternatively, if for some reason you want to retain the existing schema, I recommend you to use [PostgreSQL advisory locks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html) over locking the entire table.

Quoting from this [good introduction](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/advisory-locks-in-postgres):

> [Postgres advisory locks] are application enforced database locks.
>   Advisory locks can be acquired at the session level and at the
>   transaction level and release as expected when a session ends or a
>   transaction completes.

So you can attempt to acquire a lock before you update default state, and if it succeeds then update the table and thenafter release it. In case of failure in acquiring the lock you can retry for a fixed number of times.

The advantage here is that other unrelated operations on the states table would not be hindered.

Answer (score 1):

The race condition occurs because you use two queries to set the `default` value.

How about using just one query:

```
def make_default!
  State.update_all(['default = (id = ?)', id])
end
```